# Pseudocolumn in Spark JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

I am using a query to fetch data from MYSQL as follows:

```
var df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
         .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.192:3306/retail_db")
         .option("driver" ,"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
         .option("user", "retail_dba")
         .option("password", "cloudera")
         .option("dbtable", "orders")
         .option("partitionColumn", "order_id")
         .option("lowerBound", "1")
         .option("upperBound", "68883")
         .option("numPartitions", "4")
         .load()
```

Question is, can I use a pseudo column (like `ROWNUM` in Oracle or `RRN(employeeno)` in DB2) with `option` where I specify the `partitionColumn` ?

If not, can we specify a partition column which is not a primary key ?

Answer (score 7):

> can I use a pseudo column (like ROWNUM in Oracle or RRN(employeeno) in DB2)

**TL;DR** *Probably* no.

While Spark doesn't consider constraints like `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` there is **very important** requirement for `partitionColumn`, which is not explicitly stated in the documentation - it **has to be deterministic**.

Each executor fetches it's own piece of data using separate transaction. If numeric column is not deterministic (stable, preserved between transactions), the state of data seen by Spark might be inconsistent and records might be duplicated or skipped.

Because `ROWNUM` implementations are usually volatile (depend on non stable ordering and can be affected by features like indexing) there not safe choice for `partitionColumn`. For the same reason you cannot use random numbers.

Also, some vendors might further limit allowed operations on pseudocolumns, making them unsuitable for usage as a partitioning column. [For example Oracle `ROWNUM`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm)

> Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer are always false.

might fail silently leading to incorrect results.

> can we specify a partition column which is not a primary key

Yes, as long it satisfies criteria described above.

Answer (score -1):

As per [Spark's official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) the `partitionColumn` can be any numeric column (not necessarily primary key column).

> partitionColumn must be a numeric column from the table in question.

Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Comment: Please be more specific - can it be a pseudo column ?  For example , like Oracle ROWNUM ?

Comment: have you tried using ROWNUM instead of order_id in your code?