# Extract data from Relational database using Spark(parallel) without integer column?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

Databricks documentation mentions that we have to provide 'partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound and numPartitions' values while reading data from a relational database across mulitple workers. It is also mentioned that the partitionColumn should be a integer column. How can I then make parallel reads from table that doesnt have integer column?

[Databricks Documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#manage-parallelism)

I tried using 'rownum'(source is Oracle DB) as the partition column but when i try to store the results in a dataframe, i get only the data from the first partition.

Here is the code:

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//{0}:{1}/{2}".format(hostname, port, db)



connectionProperties = {
  "user" : 'XXXXXX',
  "password" : 'XXXXXX',
  "driver" : "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
  "oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion" : "false"
}

parallel_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl,
                          table=table_name, 
                          column='rownum', 
                          lowerBound=1, 
                          upperBound=200000, 
                          numPartitions=20,
                          properties=connectionProperties)
```

When i get the count of parallel_df, i get only 200000/20 = 10000 rows. Can anyone provide any insight on how to do this parallel read?

Comment: Related to [Pseudocolumn in Spark JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47615975)

Comment: You can use `predicates` but exact usage will depend on the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i get the count of parallel_df, i get only 200000/20 = 10000
>   rows. Can anyone provide any insight on how to do this parallel read?

when you read dataframe in that way (i.e. with partititons) spark will do a query for each partition, in your case something like

```
select t.* from table t where rownum between (1, 10000)  on executor 1
select t.* from table t where rownum between (10001, 20000) on execuotr 2

and so on ...
```

from the oracle point of view queries are unrelated and rownum (as usual) will always starts from 1, so you get only first 10000 rows coming from the first query.

> Databricks documentation mentions that we have to provide
>   'partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound and numPartitions' values
>   while reading data from a relational database across mulitple workers.

True, but you don't have to do that at any cost. If your data doesn't have a column suitable for data partitioning/splitting then just don't use that feature

```
val df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=table_name, properties=connectionProperties)
```

Comment: Thanks @gtosto. Is there a way to get all the partitions into a single dataframe? Like an aggregate parameter or similar?

Comment: you **always** get all partitions in a dataframe. Dataframe (and the underlying RDD) are just an abstraction for _distributed data_